# AppleScript: how to move a mailbox to another mailbox in Apple Mail

Tags: applescript

Naively thought that would suffice:

```
tell application "Mail"
    move mailbox "complaints" of account "ACME LLC" to mailbox "customers" of account "ACME LLC"
end tell
```

What's the correct syntax?

Follow up question, how to delete a mailbox?

```
tell application "Mail"
    delete mailbox "complaints" of account "ACME LLC"
end tell
```

gives me error "AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you want to change the folder in which your mailbox is. The mailbox in which you have mailbox is the property 'container'. For instance, container of 'Sub' gives you the mailbox in which mailbox "Sub" is.

Unfortunately, this property is read only in Applescript. So you can't change it ! The work around is to create a new mail box inside your existing mail box and then move the messages between mailboxes.

Your source mailbox is named "Source" and you want to move it inside existing mailbox named "Dest" :

1) create sub mailbox with name "Source" into mailbox "Dest".

```
tell application "Mail" to set NewBox to make new mailbox with properties {name:"Dest/Source", class:container, unread count:0}
```

As you can see, Mail event handling here is a bit strange, because the path should be in the name ! fyi, I never succeed to create boxe inside boxe inside boxe. (3 levels) !

Then use the script bellow to move from Source to new "Source"

```
set BoxeSource to "Source"
set BoxeDest to "Dest/Source"
tell application "Mail" to set mailbox of every message of mailbox BoxeSource to mailbox BoxeDest
```

Comment: I wanted to move the mailbox itself into another mailbox, and make it a sub mailbox. Your solution leaves the original mailbox empty, so I would need to delete it which, as I wrote in my original message, I am not able to do.

Comment: thanks but that still leaves me with the original mailbox empty, and  I  am still unable to do a `delete SourceMailbox of account "ACME LLC"`. I am getting an "appleEvent handler error 10000". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: tell application "Mail" to delete mailbox "xxxx" where "xxxx" is the name of the mailbox to delete avec making it empty. It is working for me (El Capitain, Mail v3.9

Comment: It works on my El Capitain. I did not install Sierra yet, so I am afraid I can't help you more now. ... fyi, I never install new Apple systems until few release updates...to avoid too many bugs ;-)

Comment: it is not an issue with file permission since I am able to rename the mailboxes with `set name of mailbox "complaints" of account "ACME LLC" to "grievances"`